# Anime: Girl travels to a foreign country with an ongoing alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I'm looking for this anime where this girl went to a foreign country but there was an alien invasion. I think the anime focuses on the mecha side of the genre. Does anyone know about this anime?

I really want to watch this anime again but I forgot its name.

Comment: Hi there! :) this is still a bit vague - could you take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good anime-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in your post? For instance, did you watch that on TV? If so, which channel? When did you watch it? Info like this will increase the chances of a successful ID. Cheers!

Comment: It reminds me of one Excel Saga episode, when Excel travels to the United States. But since it's a non sense comedy, it has all the elements you pointed and a lot more. So I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be [*Muv luv Alternative total eclipse*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/11021/Muv-Luv_Alternative__Total_Eclipse)

In one or several eps they go to other countries with the aliens invading

### Synopsis

> Since 1973, an invasion of aliens upon Earth known as BETA has driven human civilization to destruction. In order to defend themselves from this enormous mass of enemy force, mankind has developed large humanoid arms called Tactical Surface Fighters and deployed them to its defense lines through out the world. However, its efforts could only slow down the impending defeat, and mankind has been forced to abandon the major areas of the Eurasian Continent. For 30 years, they have been caught in an endless war against BETA without any hopes of victory.
>
> Now in 2001, Imperial Japan faces difficulties in the development of the next-generation of Tactical Surface Fighters (TSF) as it defends the front lines of the Far East. The UN has proposed a joint development program between Imperial Japan and the United States as a part of its TSF international mutual development unit, the Prominence Project.
>
> Yui Takamura (a surface pilot of the Imperial Royal Guards of Japan) is given the responsibility of the project and sets off to Alaska. Meanwhile, Yuya Bridges, also a surface pilot of the US Army, heads to the same destination.
>
> They never had any idea just how drastically their encounter would change their fates.
>
> This story of internal dilemma takes place during the development of the new Tactical Surface Fighters, the most crucial and effective weapons against BETA. And this time, the stakes are much higher than a handful of lives and our sanity.
>
> All we can do is fight.

Comment: Could you explain how that matches the description in the question?